# Go templates and multiline string indentation

Tags: string, go, templates

So I am trying to generate a YAML file by using the `text/template` package with a template value that is a multiline string. What I am struggling with is the indentation of the template string not being at the same level of the template variable in the tpl.

The (somewhat contrived example) here:

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "text/template"
)

func main() {
    tpl := template.Must(template.New("yml").Parse(
        `routes:
  {{ . }}
`))

    value := `foo
bar`
    tpl.Execute(os.Stdout, value)
}
```

Playground: https://goplay.space/#2eK7_ELZTwA

The output I'd like to see here is obviously

```
routes:
  foo
  bar
```

and not

```
routes:
  foo
bar
```

Is there some magic prefix to avoid this?

Comment: You would have to indent in Go code, meaning pass the indented value. For this to be dynamic (to be usable at multiple levels), you'd have to register a function that also receives the depth. **But if you want YAML output, do use a YAML library.** The template engine does not know about YAML syntax, escaping and its quirks.

Comment: Yep that's what I also found out so far, but it's still annoying (not just in the yaml context here) because you also can't really do partial templates etc.

Comment: Yeah I figured so much from reading the package and also some of the coude out there. But it's also really annoying as it kinda prevents whitespace preserving partial templates etc.. 
I'm currently checking how hugo is doing as I think they solved this issue

Comment: If you insist on doing this with `text/template`, you might look at Helm for inspiration. They generate YAML using the `text/template` package, and have [some tricks](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/yaml_techniques/) for generating valid YAML.

Comment: What would be an alternative to `text/template` ?

Comment: @Tigraine: Not really sure why you'd use templates for this. I'd personally consider YAML an alternative data format to JSON, and use something like [go-yaml](https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml) instead.

Comment: It just happens to be yaml in this case.. I am trying to template a quite large yaml file where I really don't care about most of the values but only wanna set 1-2 things in it. So modelling the whole yaml in my go code is a lot more work than just setting 2-3 variables in a loop.
And as said - it just happens to be yaml. It could be any file that has significant whitespaces where the go templater would fall down because of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to handle your requirements with the following code. I used the package sprig. It provides us with features that make it easy to achieve your goal. The code is as follows:

```golang
package main

import (
    "os"
    "text/template"

    "github.com/Masterminds/sprig/v3"
)

func main() {
    tpl := template.Must(template.New("yml").Funcs(sprig.FuncMap()).Parse(
        `routes:
{{ . | indent 2 }}
`))

    value := `foo
bar`
    tpl.Execute(os.Stdout, value)
}
```

I used the method `Funcs` to pass the functions into the template engine. These functions are returned from the invocation to `sprig.FuncMap()`.

> Please note that you must invoke this function before the `Parse` otherwise it panics.

Then, I added the annotation `| indent 2` to indent our lines by two characters. If you run the code, you'll get the desired output.

A complete list of the available function can be found [here](https://masterminds.github.io/sprig/).
Let me know if this solves your issue, thanks!